# Singleton and Multithread in SpringBoot. Is it really multi thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

Since I am not working specifically on multi threads, the questions can be low level or even silly, please excuse me =)

Here is my code call flow like;

**MessageNotificationJobExecutionConfig -> AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor -> NotificationJobExecutor.execute()**

**MessageNotificationJobExecutionConfig** (finds the objects to process) and calls **AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor** inside the loop

**AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor** has **@Async("messageNotificationTaskExecutor")** annotation over the **execute()** method.

**AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor.execute()** method calls **NotificationJobExecutor.execute()**

**messageNotificationTaskExecutor** is an instance of **ThreadPoolTaskExecutor**

*Here is my question;*

If am not wrong as default **NotificationJobExecutor** has a **singletone** instance.

Even if AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor work async and use thread pool task executor, all thread call only NotificationJobExecutor instance (singletone).

I am not sure, I may misunderstand that Thread_1 calls NotificationJobExecutor.execute() and until this thread finish its job other thread wait for Thread_1. Is my inference correct ?

I think even if it looks multi thread actually it works singletone

```
@Component("messageNotificationTaskExecutor")
public class MessageNotificationThreadPoolTaskExecutor extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {

    @Value("${message.notification.task.executor.corePoolSize}")
    Integer corePoolSize;

    @Value("${message.notification.task.executor.maxPoolSize}")
    Integer maxPoolSize;

    @Value("${message.notification.task.executor.queueCapacity}")
    Integer queueCapacity;

    public MessageNotificationThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        super();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.setCorePoolSize(corePoolSize);
        super.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
        super.setQueueCapacity(queueCapacity);
    }

}
```

```
@Configuration
public class MessageNotificationJobExecutionConfig {

    protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor asyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor;

    @Autowired
    MessageNotificationThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    JobExecutionRouter jobExecutionRouter;

    @Autowired
    NotificationJobService notificationJobService;

    private Integer operationType = OperationType.ACCOUNT_NOTIFICATION.getValue();

    @Scheduled(cron = "${message.notification.scheduler.cronexpression}")
    public void executePendingJobs() {
        
        List<NotificationJob> nextNotificationJobList = notificationJobService.findNextJobForExecution(operationType, 10);

        for (NotificationJob nextNotificationJob : nextNotificationJobList) {
            if (threadPoolTaskExecutor.getActiveCount() < threadPoolTaskExecutor.getMaxPoolSize()) {
                asyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor.execute(nextNotificationJob);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor {
    
    @Autowired
    NotificationJobExecutor notificationJobExecutor;

    @Autowired
    NotificationJobService notificationJobService;
    
    @Async("messageNotificationTaskExecutor")
    public void execute(NotificationJob notificationJob) {
            notificationJobExecutor.execute(notificationJob);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class NotificationJobExecutor implements JobExecutor {
    
    @Override
    public Integer getOperationType() {
        return OperationType.ACCOUNT_NOTIFICATION.getValue();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getOperationTypeAsString() {
        return OperationType.ACCOUNT_NOTIFICATION.name();
    }
    
    @Override
    public void execute(NotificationJob notificationJob) {
        // TODO: 20.08.2020 will be execute 
    }
    
}
```

Comment: They don't wait, there is nothing syncronized in your class. So multiple threads are allowed to call the same instance. The fact that something is a singleton doesn't mean 1 thread at a time can access the object. Your sample is overly complex and convoluted it already schedules stuff that calls an async method. So it is async twice. You don't need the subclass either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scenario you created you have all singleton instances. But the flow looks something like this:

1. call to `executePendingJobs` in `MessageNotificationJobExecutionConfig`
2. iterate over each `NotificationJob` sequentially (so this is waiting)
3. call to `execute` in `AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor` which will add a execution to the `messageNotificationTaskExecutor` sequential (thus blocking) to the thread pool
4. execute the job created in step 3 in a separate thread (so this actually executes your method in `AsyncMessageNotificationJobExecutor`
5. a blocking call to the `execute` method in `NotificationJobExecutor`

The 'magic' happens in step 3, where rather then executing the method Spring will add a job to the `messageNotificationTaskExecutor` which wraps the call to step 4. This causes the call for step 4 to happen asynchronous and thus multiple calls to the same instance can occur at the same time. So make sure this object is stateless.